# graphql prisma nodejs postgresql how to add date created/update fild to graphql type?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, graphql, prisma

I am using `graphql` + `prisma` (in docker locally), `nodejs` and `postgresql`.
 How can I make it add some fields like `created/edited` date?

For example . I have this type:

```
type Post {
  id: ID! @unique
  title: String!
  content: String!
  published: Boolean! @default(value: "false")
  author: User!
}
```

How can i add field like date. Make it equal to date the element created/updated?

Answer (score 2):

Make this change in datamodel.prisma:

```
type Post {
  id: ID! @unique
  title: String!
  content: String!
  published: Boolean! @default(value: "false")
  author: User!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  createdAt: DateTime!
}
```

Make this change in schema.graphql:

```
updatedAt: String!
createdAt: String!
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 fields hidden by default on each type you create in Prisma, but they're always created and kept up to date in the background: `createdAt: DateTime!` and `updatedAt: DateTime!`. To expose them, simply add them to your type and try querying them, you should see that there's data already.

Also note that they can't be deleted, by removing them from your schema you hide them again.

Hope this helps.